# Why isn't url-http-end-of-headers set correctly when using url-automatic-caching?

Tags: url

This is a follow-up question to [How can I make url.el work with the If-None-Match header?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/32939/2264)

Evaluate the following form:

```
(let ((url-request-method "GET")
      (url-automatic-caching t))
  (with-current-buffer
      (url-retrieve-synchronously
       "https://api.github.com/users/octocat")
    (message "'%c' (%S)"
             (char-after url-http-end-of-headers)
             url-http-end-of-headers)))
```

It thinks `url-http-end-of-headers` is position 1 in the following buffer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Fri, 19 May 2017 12:18:32 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Status: 200 OK
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 55
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1495197406
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Vary: Accept
ETag: W/"d093767a41c43cbc64dcc3bda1b5880f"
Last-Modified: Wed, 17 May 2017 21:18:07 GMT
X-GitHub-Media-Type: github.v3; format=json
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Served-By: 075bb2f6b7031ca3c0e69edb17939fae
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-GitHub-Request-Id: E86D:15875:2064CAA:268A8E5:591EE291

{"login":"octocat","id":583231,...}
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce in Emacs 26.2, I got `(#<marker at 1034 in  *http api.github.com:443*>)`, which is the position of the newline at the end of the headers.

Comment: @npostavs that is consistent with what we've seen on #81. I wonder then if this question is no longer relevant.

Comment: I don't think #81 (aka [Emacs Bug#34341](https://debbugs.gnu.org/34341)) is related, in that case (gnutls v3.6+) the response buffer is entirely empty.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in emacs at `url-cache-extract` with its use of `erase-buffer` and wiping out that marker. More details when I'm not mobile. I'll be submitting a bug report :-)

---

This seems to be a bug in either `url-http-parse-headers` or
`url-cache-extract`.  Before `url-http-parse-headers` calls
`url-cache-extract`, `url-http-end-of-headers` is set correctly.
However, when `url-cache-extract` calls `erase-buffer` to replace the
response buffer (which has header HTTP-304), `url-http-end-of-headers`
is blown away (rightly so), but not reset.

Redefining `url-cache-extract` to find the end of the headers and set
the marker appropriately should fix the immediate issue, but I'll be
reporting this bug to Emacs' bug tracker since I'm pretty sure this
isn't *all* that needs to happen in this case.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: @imalison no updates, but you might be interested in the discussion at https://github.com/magit/ghub/issues/81 which describes a similar problem (though I doubt it's exactly the same). It may need to be brought up on emacs-devel again, but I regret that I don't have the time to do this right now or in the near future, so I'd recommend you do so if you need a fix.